# SQL How can I GROUP it by the name of the regions, and get the number of all trips? oracle databes

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, count

PROBLEM TO SOLVE: Return the number and average trip length (in seconds) by the names of the regions of the starting station for the trip in 2018. How  can I GROUP it by the name of the regions, and get the number of all trips? ORACLE DATABASE

QUERY

```
SELECT  r.name,r.region_id,t.start_date, ((END_DATE - START_DATE)*24*3600)interval_sec
    FROM stations_info si
    LEFT OUTER JOIN regions r
    ON si.region_id = r.region_id
    JOIN trips t
    ON si.station_id = t.start_station_id
    WHERE start_date > TO_DATE('18/01/01') 
    ORDER BY  t.start_date ASC;
```

RESULT

```
     NAME    Reg_ID Start_Date  Interval_sec
     San Jose   5   18/01/01    145
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    1942,999999999999999999999999999999999998
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    1867
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    1140,999999999999999999999999999999999998
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    1452,000000000000000000000000000000000004
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    714
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    1209,000000000000000000000000000000000004
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    474
     Oakland    12  18/01/01    296
San Francisco   3   18/01/01    587
```

FIRST TABLE: REGIONS

```
 REGION_ID NAME                      
         3 San Francisco             
         5 San Jose                  
        12 Oakland                   
        13 Emeryville                
        14 Berkeley                  
        23 8D
```

SECOND TABLE include columns:

```
STATION_ID
NAME
SHORT_NAME
REGION_ID
RENTAL_METHODS
CAPACITY
EXTERNAL_ID
RENTAL_URL
EIGHTD_HAS_KEY_DISPENSER
HAS_KIOSK
STATION_GEOM
```

THIRD TABLE include columns:

```
TRIP_ID
START_DATE
START_STATION_ID
END_DATE
END_STATION_ID
BIKE_NUMBER
ZIP_CODE
SUBSCRIBER_TYPE
C_SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE
MEMBER_BIRTH_YEAR
MEMBER_GENDER
BIKE_SHARE_FOR_ALL_TRIP
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You query looks pretty good. You can turn it to an aggregate query as follows:

```
select  
    r.name,
    r.region_id,
    sum(end_date - start_date)*24*60*60 interval_sec  -- aggregate function
from stations_info si
inner join regions r on si.region_id = r.region_id
inner join trips t on si.station_id = t.start_station_id
where t.start_date >= date '2018-01-01' and t.start_date < date '2019-01-01'
group by r.name, r.region_id                          -- group by clause
order by r.name;
```

Side notes:

- I would suggest using date litteral (`date '2018-01-01'`) instead of relying on the default nls settings of your database or session (`TO_DATE('18/01/01')`)
- I fixed the conditions on the dates so it filters on 2018 only
- I suspect your `left join` on `regions` should probably be an `inner join` (but you can change it back if that is something you need)

Comment: This query gives me back an error: 00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 5

Comment: @AhmadSharma: just fixed a few issues, can you give it another try? If you get an error, please give me the full error message.

Comment: `inner outer join` - that's a very special join.

Comment: Thank you GMB it's closer to the solution. The last thing i need is A NUMBER OF completed trips. How can i count it ?

Comment: @AhmadSharma: just add a new column with `count(*)`